# What would explain different behavior of SWT application depending on which OS version its launcher executable was compiled on?

Tags: java, macos, swt, objective-c++

I have a Java SWT application which for Mac OS X comes with its own launcher executable that shows a splash screen and then creates the JVM and starts the actual Java application. When I build the launcher executable on Mac OS X 10.9.5, everything runs fine on OS X 10.9.5 and 10.11.5. When I, however, build it on 10.11.5, everything still runs fine on 10.9.5, but on 10.11.5 I run into an SWT exception, when the main window is created:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.getClientArea(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar.relayout(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar.createItem(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolItem.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TrimArea.createTrimArea(TrimArea.java:27)
    at com.foobar.ui.swt.MainWindow.createTopArea(MainWindow.java:3290)
    at com.foobar.ui.swt.MainWindow.createContents(MainWindow.java:3317)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
    at com.foobar.ui.swt.Foobar.createMainWindow(Foobar.java:2081)
    at com.foobar.ui.swt.Foobar.openOrImportDocument(Foobar.java:2038)
    at com.foobar.ui.swt.Foobar.openDocument(Foobar.java:1739)
    at com.foobar.ui.swt.Foobar.openDocument(Foobar.java:1728)
    at com.foobar.ui.swt.Foobar.startDocument(Foobar.java:1607)
    at com.foobar.ui.swt.Foobar.startDialogClosed(Foobar.java:1591)
    at com.foobar.ui.swt.startdialog.StartDialog.close(StartDialog.java:364)
    at com.foobar.ui.swt.startdialog.StartDialog.close(StartDialog.java:533)
    at com.foobar.ui.swt.startdialog.CreateDocumentPage$4.widgetSelected(CreateDocumentPage.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendSelectionEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Link.textView_clickOnLink_atIndex(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseDownSuper(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseDown(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseDown(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowSendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowSendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationSendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.foobar.ui.swt.Main.main(Main.java:44)
```

The launcher executable is compiled and linked from the same source with `-mmacosx-version-min=1.7` using Xcode 6.1.1 (directly using clang++ 600.0.56 (Apple LLVM 6.0) from a makefile) in both cases. There's a small size difference (39264 vs. 39728 bytes). The information I get out of otool are almost identical, though: The disassembly (`otool -vt`) is the same. The load commands show a different "current version" for the dependencies, but the same "compatibility version". The 64 bit segment (fileoff 24576) differs in size (14688 vs. 15152 bytes) as does the code signature (dataoff 29728, datasize 9536 vs. 10000) that is apparently included in the 64 bit segment.

So over all it seems only the code signature has changed in size (it's signed with the same key, though) and the "current version" values of the dependencies are different. Nothing I would expect to result in a functional difference. So my main question is: What could make the two executables behave differently on OS X 10.11.5?

I haven't really explored the SWT side of things yet. SWT 4.4.2 is used. A quick look at `Scrollable.getClientArea()` suggests that a private view handle of the SWT Cocoa port might be null.

For sake of completeness: The JDK used is a bundled Oracle's JDK 8u65, but the exception can be reproduced with 8u92 as well. The same happens when using Xcode 7.3.1 instead of 6.1.1.

**Update**: Here's simplified version of the launcher executable's code (main.cpp, error handling removed):

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

#include <string>
#include <vector>

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

#include <jni.h>

typedef jint (JNICALL* JNI_CreateJavaVM_t)(JavaVM** p_vm, void** p_env, void* vm_args);

static const char* const kMainClass = "com/foobar/ui/swt/Main";
static const char* const kJarName = "foobar.jar";

static void startJvm(JNI_CreateJavaVM_t createJavaVM,
    const std::string& basePath, char pathSeparator)
{
    // prepare JVM args
    std::vector<std::string> vmArguments;
    vmArguments.push_back(std::string("-Djava.library.path=") + basePath + "/MacOS");
    std::string classpath = "-Djava.class.path=";
    classpath += basePath + "/java/" + kJarName + pathSeparator + basePath + "/java/*";
    vmArguments.push_back(classpath);
    vmArguments.push_back("-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8");
    vmArguments.push_back("-Xms64m");
    vmArguments.push_back("-Xmx512m");
    vmArguments.push_back("-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow");

    JavaVMInitArgs vmArgs;
    size_t vmArgumentCount = vmArguments.size();
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[vmArgumentCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < vmArgumentCount; i++)
        options[i].optionString = const_cast<char*>(vmArguments[i].c_str());

    vmArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vmArgs.nOptions = vmArgumentCount;
    vmArgs.options = options;
    vmArgs.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

    // load and initialize a Java VM
    JavaVM* jvm;
    JNIEnv* env;
    createJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vmArgs);
    delete options;

    // call main method
    jclass mainClass = env->FindClass(kMainClass);
    jmethodID mainMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(mainClass, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    jclass stringClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
    jobjectArray mainArgsArray = env->NewObjectArray(0, stringClass, NULL);

    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(mainClass, mainMethod, mainArgsArray);

    // Java exited, destroy the JVM
    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
}

int main(int argc, const char* const* argv)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // get the bundle Contents path
    NSBundle* mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString* contentsPath = [[mainBundle bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contents"];

    // find the bundled JRE
    NSString* jreName = nil;
    NSFileManager* fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSString* plugInsPath = [contentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PlugIns"];
    NSArray* plugIns = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:plugInsPath
                        error:nil];
    NSUInteger plugInCount = [plugIns count];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < plugInCount; i++) {
        NSString* plugIn = [plugIns objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([plugIn hasSuffix:@".jdk"]) {
            jreName = plugIn;
            break;
        }
    }

    // load the jvm library and get the symbol
    NSString* libjvmPath = [plugInsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:jreName];
    libjvmPath = [libjvmPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib"];
    void* library = dlopen([libjvmPath fileSystemRepresentation], RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    JNI_CreateJavaVM_t createJavaVM = (JNI_CreateJavaVM_t)dlsym(library, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");

    std::string basePath = [contentsPath fileSystemRepresentation];

    [pool drain];

    // start the JVM
    startJvm(createJavaVM, basePath, ':');

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation command line:

```
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.7 clang++ -Wall -O3 -ObjC++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 \
  "-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin" \
  "-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/include" \
  -o Foobar main.cpp -framework AppKit
```

**Update 2:** Comparing the otool output and the hex dumps of the simplified executables, I verified that they really the only differ in the load commands `LC_UUID`, `LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX` (the "sdk" field (10.10 instead of 10.9)) and `LC_LOAD_DYLIB` (the "current version" field). With a hex editor I could narrow down the relevant difference to the "current version" of /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib. A version equal to or greater than 1198.0.0 causes the issue, a value up to 1197.255.255 is fine.

So my question narrows down to: What effect on the OS X libraries, Java or SWT does a `LC_LOAD_DYLIB` "current version" field equal to or greater than 1198.0.0 for /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib have that could explain the behavioral difference I'm seeing?

Comment: I would think to stand any chance of getting help you need to tag this with the programming language that the **launcher** is written in and show us a minimal version of the source code.

Comment: @greg-449: Fair enough. I've added a simplified version of the code and added the tag `objective-c++`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the handle of SWT control in Mac 64 bit cocoa enviornment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889540/how-to-get-the-handle-of-swt-control-in-mac-64-bit-cocoa-enviornment)